# Change account profile photo on network account

Tags: macos, active-directory

We have recently joined three iMacs to our Active Directory domain. I would like to set the account profile photo, however this seems to be disabled for network accounts (I can set it for local accounts).

Is there any way to set the profile photo for network accounts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the account as a Mobile account has re-enabled the display photo option.